# React and Tailwind - reading custom breakpoint value from the config

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, tailwind-css, config

I want to conditionally change the component prop based on the window width value.

I have added an `xs` breakpoint value to the `tailwind.config.cjs`.

```ts
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors');

module.exports = {
  content: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    screens: {
      xs: '480px',
      ...defaultTheme.screens,
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'primary-green': colors.green['600'],
        'off-white': '#fafafa',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

I have created a custom Hook to extract the breakpoint value from the Tailwind theme.

`theme.ts` file:

```ts
import resolveConfig from 'tailwindcss/resolveConfig';
import tailwindConfig from 'tailwind.config.cjs';

export default resolveConfig(tailwindConfig);
```

And the Hook:

```ts
import theme from 'lib/theme';

function useBreakpointValue(breakpointValue: string) {
  const breakpoint = theme.theme.screens[breakpointValue];
  return Number(breakpoint.slice(0, breakpoint.indexOf('px')));
}

export default useBreakpointValue;
```

Everything works fine when I use the predefined Tailwind breakpoint values.

```ts
  const breakpoint = useBreakpointValue('sm'); // works fine
```

But does not work with my custom `xs` value.

```ts
  const breakpoint = useBreakpointValue('xs'); // undefined - the app crashes
```

I can't figure it out.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To use your custom **XS** value, move your custom breakpoint to `extend.screens`

```
......
......
module.exports = {
 content: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  theme: {
   screens: {
     // Move this to extend.screen
     // xs: '480px',
     //...defaultTheme.screens,
    },
   extend: {
    screens: {
      xs: "475px",
       ...defaultTheme.screens,
    },
    colors: {
    'primary-green': colors.green['600'],
     .....
     ....
    },
},
},},
```

Refer - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens#adding-smaller-breakpoints

Comment: Since the new breakpoint is defined within `extend.screens`, spreading the screens from the default theme could also be omitted (since the newly defined option would be appended to the breakpoints that are already defined)